# Stage Parallelization in Jenkins declarative pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am trying to get a Jenkins (2.204.2) declarative pipeline to run **parallel stages generated into a map** on different machines. I am aware it can be done by mixing in the `script` block and I have done it that way in the past, but from documentation and other Stack____ questions I cannot figure out why this format does not work.

I have stripped everything down as far as possible and I am trying to just create the map statically outside the pipeline to figure out the syntax I need.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def map = [:]
map['Passed Stage'] = {
    stage("Passed Map Inner Stage"){
        agent{ label "nodeLabel" }
        steps{
            echo "PASSED MAP STEP"
        }
    }   
}

pipeline {
    agent { label "nodeLabel" }
    stages {
        stage("Non map stage"){
            agent{ label "nodeLabel" }
            steps{
                echo "NON MAP STEP"
            }
        }
        stage("Direct Map Outer Parallel Stage"){
            parallel{ direct : 
                stage("Direct Map Inner Stage"){
                    agent{ label "nodeLabel" }
                    steps{
                        echo "DIRECT MAP STEP"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Passed Map Outer Parallel Stage"){
            parallel{ map }
        }
    }
}
```

The first two stage methods work if I comment out the mapped one but "Passed Map Outer Parallel Stage" always fails with:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 33: Expected a stage @ line 33, column 23.
               parallel{ map }
                         ^

WorkflowScript: 33: No stages specified @ line 33, column 13.
               parallel{ map }
               ^

WorkflowScript: 33: No stages specified @ line 33, column 13.
               parallel{ map }
               ^

3 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Finished: FAILURE
```

The stage format seems fine from everything I've spent reading all day, and passing the same stage directly to `parallel` outside the map works fine.

What am I missing here? why won't `parallel` accept my map? Does declarative `parallel` only accept stages statically passed? Is my Jenkins version too low?

Answer (score 0):

The Scripted version of `parallel` and the Declarative version of `parallel` are different functions.  The Scripted version takes a Map as an argument, whereas the Declarative version expects a block with calls to the `stage` function within that block.

Comment: After 2 days of struggling against it i was starting to assume this was the case... Is this documented anywhere?